# Is there a way to make the OWL API stop defining things in the wrong ontology file?

Tags: owl-api

In my own application as well as in Protege, the OWL API adds definitions for things that an ontology mentions. This causes a large set of ontology files to become unmaintainable. The [Financial Industry Business Ontology Team](http://www.omg.org/hot-topics/finance.htm) has moved away from the OWL API in their tooling for this reason. Is there a way to make the OWL API not define classes and properties that belong under the jurisdiction of another ontology file to a mentioning ontology file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When saving an ontology, you can pass an `OWLDocumentFormat` instance. It has a `setAddMissingTypes(boolean)` method that allows you to disable adding missing declarations.

However missing declarations should be added only if no declaration is found in the imports closure, which, from your description, seems to not be the case. If you have an example of an ontology where this happens, I'd be happy to check whether it's a bug.

Comment: We'll play with that on Monday and let you know if there's a bug. Thanks.